# How can I make a javafx program that takes a number or two and calls a method from another class with that information?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

```
public ComplexNum add(ComplexNum c){
    double addedReal = (this.real + c.real);
    double addedImag = (this.imag + c.imag);
    System.out.println(addedReal);
    return new ComplexNum(addedReal,addedImag);
}
```

This is one of the simpler methods. I want to make a controller class that lets a user enter the first number, press an addition button, enter the second number, press enter, and then have the string representation of the return value printed to a label. I'm not sure how I can call the right method using the controller. I though that maybe I should have a method that checks for specific text(say "add") from the button pressed and executes the correct method for it but I feel like that's not the right way.
I basically want the first number entered to be treated as the "this" pointer for each of the methods, and any following numbers as the parameter.

Comment: Why not implement static methods for the basic operations (expecting always two `ComplexNum` Objects as paramters) and call the method(s) based on user input?

Comment: @Turing85 I had though about it but it's for a school assignment and the teacher wants us to do it this way  but he is letting us just pop up swing panels. I wanted to go a bit further and do it in javaFx

Comment: What does your UI look like?  A single TextField with an "+" button, and a Label which shows the result?  If the user presses plus it adds to the previous value, and if they hit enter it shows it?

Comment: @purringpigeon Basically but I have a total of 13 buttons if you include and 'enter' button. The user inputs a number to the textField, it's stored into a value in the controller, and then the user presses one of the functions like the "+" and it either allows for another number or simply prints the result(ex: one of the functions just returns the absolute value of the number entered).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an action listener on the button. Example using JavaFX 8:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setText("Button Text");
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Button Clicked!");
});
```

For you `ENTER` input, you need to add an event handler to your node. E.g.:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent key) -> {
    if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        System.out.println("ENTER pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: To handle <kbd>enter</kbd>, it is probably better to call [`button.setDefaultButton(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-).  If additionally, it is desired to have a focussed TextField respond to <kbd>enter</kbd> then an [onAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) handler should be added to the TextField.

Comment: I think OP expects only one button, which adds another number, so `ENTER` shouldn't be associated with it.

Comment: One button with enter associated with it is exactly what a default button is for.  Whether that is what the asker expects, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (this obviously is incomplete) hopefully can point you in a direction:

```
long runningTotal = 0;
Button plusButton = new Button("+");
Button enterButton = new Button("Enter");
TextField tf = new TextField();
Label displayLabel = new Label();

//Setup you UI here

plusButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    String stringValue = tx.getText();
    long value = Long.parseLong(stringValue);
    runningTotal = runningTotal + value;
});

enterButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    //if you need to remember your last pressed button, you could have done that also, then perform that action here
    displayLabel.setText("" + runningTotal);
});
```